# Comments in CSS make it wrong

Tags: css, comments

#### Situation

I recently decided to put comments in my CSS files. And once I did so, one of them stopped working.

Both ways of making comments make my entire CSS file not to work. I know this is lacking informations, I just don't know where it could even possibly come from.

In case it does matter, this is how I write my CSS:

```css
// Background
body            { background-color: #666666; }
#content            { background-color: #cccccc; }
#menu           { background-color: #cccccc; }
#menu-footer        { background-color: #33cccc; }
#menu-items a.active    { background-color: #33cccc; }
#menu-items a:hover     { background-color: #99cccc; }

// The white spaces are actually tabs (Alt+i on Emacs)
```

---

#### Update 1

I am looking for ways to *debug* this situation. I see my CSS files in the developer tool from Google Chrome, but properties are not applied.

```
foobar {
    // color: cyan;
}
```

Does this simply make the CSS wrong but only on the one line ? So the rest of the file keep getting parsed ?

---

#### Update 2

I always used `//` to comment my CSS but with the later notation I used in this post. Now that I changed my mind and am using inline CSS, `//` being an invalid token make the whole file not readable.

Comment: Same story.  Formally learning js html and css and starting out with // in css with some interesting results that could not be explained :}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[css](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#comments) does not recognize the double slash as a comment. You have to use the 
`/* */` one.

I might be wrong, but since the double slash is not a valid css token the behaviour might be browser dependent. I would expect browsers to simply ignore the property or the statement that follows the `//`, but I never checked/tested.

There are [rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#parsing-errors) on what browsers should do in various situations, however I did not see any for unknown token (maybe a I didn't look well enough).

Answer (score 2):

Use  */ Text */ ,  instead of // (// is comment in javascript)

```
/* Comment */
```

For Example

```
/**** Background ****/
    body            { background-color: #666666; }
    #content            { background-color: #cccccc; }
    #menu           { background-color: #cccccc; }
    #menu-footer        { background-color: #33cccc; }
    #menu-items a.active    { background-color: #33cccc; }
    #menu-items a:hover     { background-color: #99cccc; }

/* The white spaces are actually tabs (Alt+i on Emacs) */
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the comments this way

```
/* Background */
body            { background-color: #666666; }
#content            { background-color: #cccccc; }
#menu           { background-color: #cccccc; }
#menu-footer        { background-color: #33cccc; }
#menu-items a.active    { background-color: #33cccc; }
#menu-items a:hover     { background-color: #99cccc; }

/* The white spaces are actually tabs (Alt+i on Emacs) */
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to comment in CSS is by `/* this is a comnent */`

```
/*This is a comment*/
p
{
text-align:center;
/*This is another comment*/
color:black;
font-family:arial;
}
```